# Generating Variables in SAS by Option

Tags: variables, sas, stata

So I'm wondering if there is a way to basically replicate the egen option in SAS.  Right now, I am trying to find the mean of a variable by a certain group so I use the proc means feature and output a dataset with that information. Then I merge that dataset with the dataset I used in the proc means feature.  I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

So this is what I do

```
proc means dataset=data noprint; 
var volume;
class hour;
output out=newdataset sum(volume)=sumvolume;
run;
```

Then I merge this using a left join with the original dataset called data

```
proc sql; 
select a.*,b.sumvolume
from data as a
left join newdataset as b
on a.hour=b.hour;
quit;
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this, but I wouldn't necessarily say there's a truly easier way.  That's certainly the "SAS" way to do that, and it's not exactly complicated or time consuming.

You can do it in one SQL step, if you don't mind cheating a bit.

```
proc sql; 
 create table want as
  select *, sum(volume) as volumesum
  from have
  group by hour;
quit;
```

That's illegal in most SQL flavors, but SAS converts it to an automatic join (ie, it does the group by properly to calculate the sum, then joins it back to the original record-level table).  It's not really different from what you're doing above; it might be a little faster (since you really only read the data once), or it might be a little slower (since `PROC MEANS` is optimized in ways `PROC SQL` can't be), but I suspect they'll be similar in overall performance (but test them!).

You could do the mean in the datastep, but again it wouldn't really be fundamentally different: a step to calculate the mean, and a step to get that back on the data.

```
data want;
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.hour);
  set have;
  by hour;
  volumesum + volume;
end;
do _n_=1 by 1 until (last.hour);
  set have;
  by hour;
  output;
end;
volumesum=0;
run;
```

That also will probably read the data in once (as long as the groups by hour aren't too big to fit in your BUFSIZE/BUFNO settings).